# Why are these corny keg relief valves different?

Tags: keg, corny-keg

My old valve (on the right) was leaking so ordered a new one from Amazon. It was the only kind I could find so assumed they were all the same. It doesn't seem to fit my keg though. Can someone tell me what "style" my old one is so I can order the correct one?

[image: valve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the vent hole in the keg lid for the old valve (on the right) was 3/16". The new valve appears to be for a 1/4" hole so ended up drilling out the vent hole in the lid. Maybe this will be helpful to anyone else stumbling across the same thing. Seems to seal OK with the new valve. *shrug*